# Is it possible to understand which are really running and which are waiting for CPU time?

Tags: java, multithreading, profiling

Is it possible in java to understand if my thread is actually running or is it waiting for CPU to give it some time? It looks like it is not mapped to java thread states (like BLOCKED, WAITING, etc.)

I have started 50 CPU-intensive threads on a 4 CPU machine. All of these threads are shown as "RUNNABLE". jstack / jvisualvm are showing all of them as runnable. Tasks are not using native code exxplicitly.

Comment: Runnable means that it scheduled or running. What do you want to do?

Comment: I don't suppose Java has any need to care whether they're running or not. In most systems, that's the operating system scheduler's job.  In any case, if all 4 CPUs were occupied with running your compute threads, you asking what was running would have to pre-empt one of them.

Comment: I don’t know the details, but I suspect you’ll find thread debugging and monitoring is being revamped now as part of the *Project Loom* technology being previewed in Java 19 for [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425), [structured concurrency](https://openjdk.org/jeps/428), and more. The Loom changes meant some serious reworking of Java internals. You may find improved thread debugging/monitoring features in the IDEs soon, perhaps in their early access versions.